# Cross Site Publishing - Error displaying item page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 404, cross-site-publishing

After configuring cross site publishing and connecting to my catalog I am presented with my catalog page with my items listed however whenever I select either the item in the catalog or the term in the navigation bar I am presented with

> The page you are looking for doesn't exist.

I have disconnected and reconnected the catalog, crawled and recrawled, pointed to catalog and items pages in the term store and still no joy.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if all pages are checked in and major version is published.